# ui-grid with selection does not recive focus for ng-copy

Tags: angularjs, ui-grid

I want to fire custom ctrl method when the user types ctrl+c on ui-grid.
It works fine unless I use a ui-grid-selection plugin for ui-grid.
The problem is that when the user clicks on table row ui-grid div does not receive focus.

Here I provide a demo to reproduce this scenario:

```
demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/KcGSwRuZ077B8ELlE39q?p=preview
```

Both tables have copied data div under it to see if ctrl+c works.
The first table has ui-grid-selection enabled and it does not receive focus.

Any idea how to achieve this?